# Vulnerability with NSS

Tags: 20.04, vulnerability

A recent vulnerability regarding NSS has been found (https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-43527). Is there any way to upgrade an Ubuntu 20.04 system to meet the minimum requirements and avoid this vulnerability? Thanks.

Comment: Step 1: Check the CVE tracker at https://ubuntu.com/security/cve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-43527:

The affected packages have already been patched, and those patched packages are already in the Ubuntu repositories. You should have received them automatically around 01 December 2021 -- that's what Unattended Upgrades does.

The patched version of `nss` in Ubuntu 20.04 is `2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.6`

Comment: My installation returned 0.16.1-1ubuntu0.1 as the aide version. There is no change in nss (still 2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.6) so I guess that the only way to check out if the patch is effective would be rescanning (which will take some time).

Comment: Re-read the corrected answer. The `aide` package was a mistake. You are already running the patched version of nss.

Comment: Run `apt-get changelog libnss3`. It says CVE-2021-43527 has been patched last year.

Comment: The changelog seems to point to 29/11/2021 as the date that the patch was installed. I think that I got it. Thanks.